# Cloning a project image from Raspberry Pi 4 (SD) to CM3+ (eMMC)

Tags: compute-module

I'm relatively new to Raspberry Pi platform, and I made a project on Raspberry Pi 4 working on a 32Gb SD card.

Now that my project is up and running I need to transfer it to an industrial extension board based on CM3+ (16Gb onboard eMMC).

However, I cannot find a way to clone my SD card on to the CM3+. I've tried different approaches but haven't succeeded yet, and now I'm stuck on this. Although I can easily install a new (clean) official Raspberry Pi OS image on CM3+, any attempt to deploy a copy image of my SD card fails.

What I actually do is as follows:

- I clone my SD card on Mac OS X by using the ApplePiBaker software, which results in an .img file on my Mac local drive
- The image file size is ~32Gb, which corresponds to my SD card size
- As the eMMC of the CM3+ is only 16Gb, I tried to upload the image onto it two ways: A. By first truncating the .img file to something ~10Gb (by using the dd tool), getting rid of the empty space from the image, and making sure the resulting cut image mounts on Mac flawlessly; B. By uploading it to CM3+ "as is", and then it just uploads as much as it can - i.e., 16Gb (with surprisingly no error upon exit)
- Anyway, the result is the same: launching the CM3+ ends up with a Linux "kernel panic" (please take a look at the photo attached)

Need help to troubleshoot this issue, would appreciate any particular advice.

[image]

Comment: Your attempting to clone the drive that was built on one piece of hardware and use it on another, even though they are both PI's, one's a 4 and the other is a 3, so there are many differences. Depending on your project, your best bet to is to consolidate the files/programs/ect that you need and move them over to a running image on the CM3+.  There are many parts of the full disk image that are tailored to the device that it runs on, you cant just copy the entire image to new hardware and expect it to work.

Comment: I will give it a final try by copying my system image on a 8Gb SD card (so it fits the eMMC) and then reflashing the CM3+. If it fails, I will follow your advice and re-build the system completely from scratch. Thanks for your feedback.